# php перебор массива, и сравнение с частью переменной через regexp

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста как перебрать массив и сравнить его значения с частью переменной? 
Я сам не программист, сильно не пинайте, комплектую код из разных кусочков)

Этот код судя по всему не работает)

```
$cli = $result. "&nbsp;" .$client.  "&nbsp;" .$userAgent. "&nbsp;" .$rf;
$file = file("ip.txt");
foreach ($file as $value) {

if (preg_match("/($value)/", $cli)) {
    {$nume=3;}
}
```

1. Сначала беру данные о посетителе. Ip, юзерагент, провайдер.
   Но этой части кода тут нет.
2. Эти данные объединяю в

```php
$cli = $result. "&nbsp;" .$client. "&nbsp;" .$userAgent. "&nbsp;" .$rf;
```

3. В файле `ip.txt` - есть список ip и провайдеров которые я хочу найти у посетителя. Беру в виде массива

```php
$file = file("ip.txt");
```

4. Далее массив перебираю в переменную `$value`:

```php
foreach ($file as $value){ /** ... */ }
```

5. А потом пытаюсь сравнить через `regex`, есть ли в данных пользователя `$cli` хотя бы одно значение из массива `$file`

```php
if (preg_match("/($value)/", $cli)){ /** ... */ }
```

6. Если значение есть то

```php
$nume=3;
```

Comment: Сначала беру данные о посетителе. 
Ip, юзерагент, поров. но этой части кода тут нет.
Эти данные обедняю в $cli

$cli = $result. "&nbsp;" .$client.  "&nbsp;" .$userAgent. "&nbsp;" .$rf;


В файле ip.txt - есть список ip и провайдеров которые я хочу найти у посетителя. Беру в виде массива $file

$file = file("ip.txt");


Далее массив перебираю  в переменную $value

foreach ($file as $value)

А потом пытаюсь сравнить через regex, есть ли в данных пользователя $cli хотя бы одно значение из массива $file

if (preg_match("/($value)/", $cli))

Если значение есть то {$nume=3;}

Comment: это нужно в вопрос писать. Нажмите на кнопку "править" под вопросом и изложите все там, чтобы это было доступно всем пользователям . Обсуждения в комментариях не все читают и многие не поняв суть вопроса из его текста могут его пропустить.

Comment: спасибо) сам за информативные связки вопрос-ответ. Но сначала думал что понятно будет только с кодом)

Comment: Михаил я не знаю что сказать. Честно даже несколько всплакнул, что бывают вот такие вот люди как Вы. Это нечто. Прочитал на одном дыхании. Надеюсь что когда нибудь мы будем работать с Вами в одном проекте-) Спасибо и Благодарю.

Comment: спасибо, приятно). благодарность авторам ответов тут галочками и плюсиками выражают: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: проходите регистрацию до конца, авось понравится жизнь в сообществе

Comment: Заранее можете прочитать справку и особенно раздел [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) чтобы понимать что от Вас ждёт сообщество, как от автора вопросов. Особенно обратите внимание на статьи: [На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). В противном случае, к сожалению, можно получить не самый положительный опыт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Далее я буду комментировать весь код построчно сверху вниз:*

## Неразрывный пробел

`&nbsp;` - это спецсимвол, который называется *"Неразрывный пробел"*
Как следует из названия, данный символ запрещает разделять *"слова"*, соединённые данным символом и используется он в `HTML`, для того чтобы устойчивые сочетания слов нельзя было разделить на несколько строк.

Использовать данный символ в других случаях не рекомендуется.
Данный символ не является заменой обычному пробелу (" ").
Более того, иногда могут возникать путаница и проблемы с поиском, заменой и разделением строк.

Поэтому если Вы, не намеревались добиться неразрывной строки в `HTML`, `&nbsp;` в данном случае лучше заменить на обычный пробел:

```php
$cli = $result. " " .$client.  " " .$userAgent. " " .$rf;
```

Это выглядит, читается и распознаётся лучше, чем оригинальный вариант.
Также можно избежать конкатенацию(соединение строк), просто поместив переменные внутрь строки(между кавычками)

```php
$cli = "{$result} {$client} {$userAgent} {$rf}";
```

или

```php
$cli = "$result $client $userAgent $rf";
```

Однако, стоит помнить, что замена переменных значениями внутри строк работает только с двойными кавычками. С одинарными замена работать не будет.

## Относительный путь

```php
$file = file("ip.txt");
```

Стоит отдавать себе отчёт в том, что данный код будет работать только тогда, когда файл `ip.txt` находится в одной папке с запущенным скриптом, потому что Вы передали относительный путь.

Во избежание ошибок, желательно передавать полный путь к файлу, начиная с корня файловой системы.Например:

```php
// для Linux
$file = file("/var/www/test/ip.txt");
// для Windows
$file = file("C:\Users\Michael\www\test\ip.txt");
```

Иногда на хостинге Вы не имеете доступа ко всей файловой системе и даже не знаете точно в какой именно папке будет расположен скрипт, но Вы знаете относительное положение скрипта и требуемых ресурсов.

В этом случае может помочь:

- константа `__DIR__` , которая хранит в себе полный путь к директории, в которой находится запущенный скрипт.
- символические ссылки на текущую `.` и родительскую `..` директории
- функция [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.realpath.php)(), которая, возвращает абсолютный канонизированный путь к файлу

Например:

```php
$filename = realpath(__DIR__."/../../config/ip_list.txt");
```

## Фигурные скобки

Рассмотрим код

```php
if (/**condition */) {
    {$nume=3;}
}
```

Данные вложенные фигурные скобки (`{$nume=3;}`) не несут никакой пользы и не имеют никакого смысла.
Данный участок лучше переписать так:

```php
if (/**condition */) {
    $nume = 3;
}
```

## Проверка наличия подстроки в строке

Я иногда и сам грешу этим, тем не менее я не рекомендую использовать функцию `preg_match()` для проверки наличия определенной подстроки в строке.
`preg_match()` отвечает за то, соответствует ли строка [регулярному выражению](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).
И это не совсем одно и тоже.

- Во-первых: вы немного усложняете код составлением регулярного выражения.
- Во-вторых: вы можете получить результаты, которые будут отличаться от ваших ожиданий из-за попадания символов, используемых в регулярных выражениях (например: точка может обозначать любой символ и т.д.)
- В-третьих: проверка регулярного выражения будет требовать больших ресурсов, что может дать знать о себе на большом объеме.

Вместо этого для проверки наличия подстроки в строке обычно используют функцию `strpos()` или её аналог для [мультибайтовых строк](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php) `mb_strpos()`

Данные функции возвращают позицию первого вхождения подстроки в строке **или `false` при её отсутствии**.

Например:

```php
echo strpos("abcdefg", "d");
// output: 3

// обратите внимание на то, что отчёт начинается с нуля
// если мы будем искать букву "a", функция вернёт 0 и это будет ее верной позицией в строке
echo strpos("abcdefg", "a");
// output: 0

// пытаемся найти подстроку, которой нет 
echo strpos("abcdefg", "z");
// output: false
```

При отсутствии же функция вернёт `false` и таким образом можно будет проверять наличие подстроки в строке.

```php
if (strpos($mystring, $findme) === false) {
    echo "Строка '$findme' не найдена в строке '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "Строка '$findme' найдена в строке '$mystring'";
    echo " в позиции $pos";
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что в данном случае для сравнения используется не `==`, а `===`.
`===` - это строгое сравнение, которое сравнивает не только значение но и тип переменной.
`php` это динамично-типизируемый язык программирования и переменные могут автоматически приводиться от одного типа к другому.
И в частности: `false` может автоматически приводиться к `0` и наоборот.

Для того чтобы исключить путаницу и возможную ошибку лучше использовать строгое сравнение.

```php
if ( 0 == false ){
    echo "0 равен false";
} else {
    echo "0 НЕ равен false";
}
// output: 0 равен false

if ( 0 === false ){
    echo "0 равен false";
} else {
    echo "0 НЕ равен false";
}
// output: 0 НЕ равен false
```

Соответственно, при проверке наличия подстроки "a" в строке "abcdefg", может возникнуть проблема, потому что `strpos("abcdefg","a")` вернёт 0, который может автоматически привестись к `false`.
Поэтому в данном случае важно использовать строгое сравнение с учетом типов переменных.

Также есть оператор сравнения `!==` (строго не равно).
И именно его стоит использовать для проверки наличия подстроки в строке следующим образом.

```php
if(strpos("abcdefg","a") !== false){
    echo "Подстрока 'а' есть в строке 'abcdefg'";
}
// output: Подстрока 'а' есть в строке 'abcdefg'
```

Таким образом вашу проверку можно написать следующим образом:

```php
if (strpos($cli, $value) !== false) {
    // ...
}
```

> **Замечание**:
> Не прошло и ста лет, как в языке php восьмой версии
> появилась функция `str_contains()`, которая
> проверяет наличия подстроки в строке,
> однако, я не рекомендую пока её использовать,
> потому что php версии 8, вы еще не скоро встретите на серверах хостингов
> и пока что эта функция имеется чуть более чем нигде
> str_contains: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-contains.php

## Результат работы функции file()

Скорее всего именно данный пункт был причиной ошибочной работы вашего скрипта.
Дело в том, что функция `file()` возвращает вам содержимое файла в виде массива строк.
Подвох состоит в том, что в конце каждой строки есть символ перехода строки(`\n`).
А это значит, что символ перехода строки также присутствует в условии поиска.
Т.е. по сути: 
Вы думаете что ищите строку `192.168.1.1`
Но на самом деле вы ищите строку `192.168.1.1\n`
которой вы закономерно не находите.

Более того регулярные выражения по умолчанию выполняют поиск в строке, а не во всем тексте и для поиска соответствия регулярному выражению в многострочном тексте нужно указывать специальные ключи. Что в очередной раз говорит о том, что лучше данную функцию(preg_match) использовать только по прямому назначению.

Соответственно, перед тем как выполнять поиск Вам желательно очистить строку от символа конца строки.
Сделать это можно с помощью функции `trim()`, передав в нее символ конца строки в качестве дополнительного параметра.

Символ конца строки можно указать как `"\n"` или с помощью константы `PHP_EOL` (EOL = End Of Line)

```php
foreach ($file as $value) {
   $line = trim($value, PHP_EOL);
   // ...
}
```

## В итоге:

```php
$cli = "$result $client $userAgent $rf";
// при условии что ip.txt находится в той же папке
// в противном случае используйте ссылки на родительские директории 
// для позиционирования файла ip.txt относительно запущенного скрипта
$file = file(__DIR__."/ip.txt"); 
foreach ($file as $value) {
    $line = trim($value, PHP_EOL);
    if (strpos($cli, $line) !== false) {
        $nume = 3;
    }
    // ...
}
```

## Проверка:

Я создал файл ip.txt со следующим содержимым:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.6
192.168.1.7
192.168.1.8
192.168.1.9
```

И выполнил данный скрипт для проверки:

```php
$result = "192.168.1.3";
$client = "some client code";
$userAgent = "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36";
$rf = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com";
$cli = "$result $client $userAgent $rf";
$file = file(__DIR__."/ip.txt");
echo $cli."\n";
foreach ($file as $value) {
    $line = trim($value, PHP_EOL);
    if (strpos($cli, $line) !== false) {
        echo "Данный клиент ($line)  имеется в списке\n";
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
192.168.1.3 some client code Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36 https://ru.stackoverflow.com
Данный клиент (192.168.1.3)  имеется в списке
```

Что значит, что данный код работает и он находит IP адрес из списка в файле.